# Alert/message forwarding in distributed system

Tags: java, design-patterns, message-queue, distributed-computing

I need to design a message forwarding system in a distributed system of two or more servers.

Like out of all the group of servers in the distributed system, one will be primary server and rest all will be fallback/secondary servers.
So if some message is generated on this secondary servers they should be forwarded to the primary server for further processing.
A message can be anything like like some health related information or simple network connectivity status.

I am very new to distributed systems and haven't worked on inter server communication.

Please suggest some technologies/design that I might learn to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely a few protocol options here. Each of these options has several implementations to choose from.

- REST (I'd suggest either [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/) or [Spring WS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/))
- SOAP (This will provide support for more complicated webservice operations like reliable messaging, but it's pretty clunky compared to REST).
- [JMS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/docs-136352.html) (Suitable for high-volume applications. Check out [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) and [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/))

REST is probably the most popular and portable solution. If you need to swap out one of the Java components for something written in C++, node.js, whatever, there will almost definitely be multiple REST client/server libraries available for it. It's also very straightforward.